# How to add tooltip/dropdown/popup to UDF/user-defined Excel 2010 function?

Tags: excel, tooltip, arguments, excel-2010, user-defined-functions

I would love to be able to add tooltip/dropdown/popup to my user-defined Excel 2010 functions.

The similar thing can be seen from VLOOKUP function as below screenshot.

If you know how to create it, please share.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible to do this (but you can do it for the function wizard with Automation or XLL)

Comment: If it is not possible, why VLOOKUP can have it?

Comment: Would you make it more clearer on `Automation or XLL`? Thank you!

Comment: There is no programmable published interface to do this: but the Excel development team can.

Comment: For Automation addins or VBA UDFs see http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/RegisterUDF00.asp for C++ XLLs see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687883.aspx

Comment: And for UDFs defined in .NET, Excel-DNA (http://exceldna.codeplex.com) makes the wizard customization easy.